# PHP xdebug profiler not showing any logs

Tags: php, apache, xdebug, centos6, profiler

I am trying to install and configure xdebug and php profiler on Centos 6.8 and the PHP version is 5.6
I am really tired with trying to solve this problem I waste more than three days on it, I tried every solution in the internet but i got nothing.
I hope if you can help me.

php --version (result)

```
`PHP 5.6.31 (cli) (built: Jul  6 2017 08:16:47) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 2002-2016, by Derick Rethans`
```

php.ini (configuration)

```
`[XDEBUG]
zend_extension = "/usr/lib64/php/modules/xdebug.so"
xdebug.profiler_append = 1
xdebug.profiler_enable = 1
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = 0
xdebug.profiler_output_dir = "/home/ehab/Desktop/debug"
xdebug.profiler_output_name = "cachegrind.out.%p"
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
xdebug.remote_mode = req
xdebug.remote_log = "/home/ehab/Desktop/debug"
xdebug.default_enable=0
xdebug.coverage_enable=0
xdebug.trace_enable_trigger=0
xdebug.auto_trace=0
xdebug.collect_includes=0
xdebug.extended_info=1
xdebug.trace_output_dir="/home/ehab/Desktop/debug"`
```

Hope to get some help

Comment: is the directory writeable by the process running php  (possibly user www-data on many nix's) ?

Comment: @YvesLeBorg do you mean apache user ??